# Issue while reading text file from batch script

Tags: parsing, batch-file

While reading text file from batch script am not able to get the values which are already present.

### doxygen.txt

Version

8.0.56336(There is no space between version and value)

### test.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set num=0
if %errorlevel%==0 (
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a IN ('"wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable'" get version"') do (
echo %%%a >> doxygen.txt
)
rem FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (doxygen.txt) DO echo %%x
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (doxygen.txt) do (
    set /a num+=1
    set v[!num!]=%%i
)
del doxygen.txt
set line1=%v[1]%
set line2=%v[2]%
set line3=%v[3]%
set line4=%v[4]%
echo line1: %line1%
echo line2: %line2%
echo line3: %line3%
echo line4: %line4%
endlocal
)
)
```

Here am not able to get the values to line1,line2 etc.

Can anyone please suggest me where I have done the mistake.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: are you supposed to have `%%%a`  in the first loop?

Comment: Even though no use Alex.The issue is still remain.

Answer (score 1):

Batch expands percent expression when a line or parenthesis block is parsed before it is executed.
So set line1=%v[1]% will simply expand to nothing, as it expands before the FOR loop even starts.

But you can use the delayed expansion syntax, as these are expanded at *runtime*.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set num=0
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a IN ('"wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable'" get version"') do (
        echo %%a>> doxygen.txt
    )
    rem FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (doxygen.txt) DO echo %%x
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (doxygen.txt) do (
        set /a num+=1
        set "v[!num!]=%%i"
    )
    del doxygen.txt
    set "line1=!v[1]!"
    set "line2=!v[2]!"
    set "line3=!v[3]!"
    set "line4=!v[4]!"
    echo line1: !line1!
    echo line2: !line2!
    echo line3: !line3!
    echo line4: !line4!
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're just trying to get the version from the output, here's an easier way to do it:

**1:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set num=0
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%v IN ('wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable'" get version ^| findstr "."') do (
        echo Version: %%v
        set mc_vcpp_05=%%v
    )
)
endlocal
```

**2:**

Here's if you need to read that file for some reason:

```
@echo off
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims= " %%a IN ('wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable'" get version ^| findstr "."') do (
        echo %%a >> doxygen.txt
    )
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%I in ('type doxygen.txt') do (
        echo Version: %%I
    )
    del doxygen.txt
)
```

Why it's behaving for you in your original script, I don't know yet.  Ill edit or comment my answer when I find out

Comment: Its good that we can get the version directly, but the thing is I need to get it from the text file.Anyway thanks a lot for your reply.